# How to show uses of function in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am used from Pycharm to be able to press ctrl + click on a function definition and see the uses. Is there an equivalent in VSC?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use 'Find All References' (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) to get a better view of usage

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tips-and-tricks#find-all-references

read this and you can get better idea

Comment: This actually does not work properly, this option is called "Find All References" in VS Code while the proper counterpart in IntelliJ is called "Find Usage", and it returns all usages, for any symbol (variable or method) while the VS Code implementations fails to find the usage and you get "No results" instead :(

Comment: I just found out that that seam to be a know bug, but a bot closed the ability to talk about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37713

Comment: update: you need a running language server for this function to run. you can find more about it here: https://github.com/sourcegraph/go-langserver and an important hint, here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1473

Comment: git grep? alt click pycharm/intellij? vscode seems to be missing basic functionality. I don't get it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for methods, which is understandable but frustrating.

Comment: This workflow is slow compared to Jetbrains IDEs where you can bring up a context menu with usages and go directly to them without having to wait for the slow ass auto-hide to close the usages menu.

Answer (score 21):

**2020-03-05 update**

You can `CTRL+CLICK` (Windows) or `CMD+CLICK` (Mac) on the function name and look on the right column.

Comment: Alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Right-click and select "**Go to References**" or "**Find All References**" from context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

There is, but VSCode doesn't support key bindings with mouse buttons. The relevant issue is [#3130](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130). That means that it will not work the same way as it works in PyCharm.

What You can do though is to use - I believe - <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> or set some key combination to show all usages of function.

To do this You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and click on 'keybinding.json' link in the sentence: "For advanced customization open and edit keybinding.json".
After getting `keybinding.json` open, add the following entry there.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
    "command": "editor.action.referenceSearch.trigger",
    "when": "editorHasReferenceProvider && editorTextFocus && !inReferenceSearchEditor"
}
```

It should let You show usages of function by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Obviously, You can customize it however You like.

I also recommend adding the following entry to close the dialog with the same key combination.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
    "command": "closeReferenceSearch",
    "when": "referenceSearchVisible && !config.editor.stablePeek"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just press `Shift+f12` on any element and it shows references.
Please check screenshots below what kind of view is shown by vscode in 2023.

[image]

You can also check shortcut here for `Go to References` if you are using any other operating system.
[image]