# How do I find functions that call a particular function?

Tags: php

I want to statically find all functions that call `foo` in a large codebase. `grep`ing results in quite a few matches and going through them one by one and manually extracting function names is not viable. How do I go about doing it? It will also be nice and convenient if I could get names of all the functions that call functions that call `foo` and so on.

Comment: Use an intelligent IDE like Jetbrains PHPStorm or Visual Studio Code. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MarkusZeller How do I get a list of all functions that call `foo` in a vscode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667459/how-to-show-uses-of-function-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Thanks, but  I need to further process those function names by piping into other command, possibly with similar functionality and I can't see how IDE can help with that. I still need to extract function names manually while using an IDE.

Comment: VSCode also fails to properly determine which class the function belongs to, so for example, it lists both `ClassA::foo()` and `ClassB::foo()` references when searching for references for `ClassA::foo()`.

Comment: As I told, try PHPStorm. It is the most powerful IDE on this planet.

Comment: If you don’t want an IDE, which I agree is your best bet, you could maybe try a static analysis tool such as PHPStan, although I don’t think it is necessarily geared towards this. In your comment, you also say you want to pipe this to another command. Based on another question of yours, I think I know what you might be trying, but it would help if you could explain it so that we don’t keep guessing, and you giving us additional restrictions.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm just trying to get a list of all functions that call `foo`, as simple as that. After looking at that list I might want to do the same for one or all of those functions. I just need a simple cli tool. I'm not familiar with PHPStan or any IDEs intimately, but at a glance they seem like a huge overkill.

Comment: You want a list, but then you want to do more programmatic logic with it, and that’s where it gets complicated. PHPStorm will give you a visual list, and more importantly allow you to do something, either manually or sometimes automatically. PHPStan is a library that might allow you to do something custom. Blackfire is another library you could look into.

Comment: @ChrisHaas So I do have to write my own script after all... I'm pretty surprised that it's not achievable with some trivial tool.

Comment: I’m not aware of any CLI tool or any library code that has such a feature natively, nor am I aware of an IDE that has the feature, and can be exported. I occasionally need to know this information, and I just use PHPStorm or `find` with `grep`, but it sounds like that’s not something for you. Such a tool might exist, but I’m just not aware of it because I personally have no need for it.